# Using the squeeze theorem to verify that $\lim \limits_{x \to 0} (x^2+1)=1$, and also using $\lim \limits_{x \to 0} (|x|+1)=1$

Tags: calculus, limits

I need help to do the following:

Use the squeeze theorem to verify that $\lim \limits_{x \to 0} (x^2+1)=1$ . (Hint: Use $\lim \limits_{x \to 0} (|x|+1)=1$)

I understand the squeeze theorem states that

if $f(x)$$\le$$g(x)$$\le$$h(x)$ when $x$ is close to $a$  (except possibly at $a$) and

$\lim \limits_{x \to a} f(x)=L$ = $\lim \limits_{x \to a} g(x)=L$

then $\lim \limits_{x \to a} h(x)=L$

But I do not know how to apply it here and use the hint. I tried graphing $f(x)=x^2+1$ and the absolute value function but that didn't help either.

Comment: $1\le x^2+1 \le |x|+1$ when $|x|\le1$

Comment: Did you mean you tried graphing $x^\mathbf2+1$ ?

Comment: Yes, I fixed it. Why is $x^2+1$ being placed between 1 and |x|+1, how did you know to place it between those two?

Comment: Well, we're supposed to use the squeeze theorem and the hint was to look at $|x|+1$ and I know that when $x$ is close to $0$ -- i.e., $|x|\le1$ -- then $x^2<|x|$

Answer (score 1):

If $|x| \le 1$ then $x^2=|x||x|\le|x|,$ so $x^2+1 \le |x|+1.$

On the other hand, for all $x \in \mathbb R,$ $0\le x^2,$ so $1 \le x^2+1.$

Therefore, $x^2+1$ is sandwiched between $1$ and $|x|+1$ when $|x| \le 1,$ an interval which contains $x=0.$

Therefore, from the well-known fact that $\lim_{x\to 0}(1)=1,$ and the hint that $\lim_{x\to 0}(|x|+1)=1,$

it follows by the squeeze theorem that $\lim_{x\to 0}(x^2+1)=1.$

Comment: Just one question, how do we know that the absolute value of x is less than or equal to 1?

Comment: Just had to show the squeeze in an interval containing $0$; the solution set to $|x|\le 1$ is an interval containing $0$ where the squeeze works